# Gunicorn worker timeout

Tags: django, nginx, timeout, gunicorn

I have a Django application running in Gunicorn behind Nginx. Everything works fine, exect for one strange thing: I have a "download" view and a RESTful json API. When call the download view I use urllib2 to access the json API to get information. And excactly when I try to do this http get request to the json api, the request times out with an error HTTP Error 504: Gateway Time-out.

When I run the code with ./manage.py runserver everything works fine. The http get request to the json api also only takes a few miliseconds, so no danger of running into a timeout.

Here the Situation in Pseudo code:

**myproject/views.py:** (accessible as: http://myproject.com/download)

```
1   def download(request, *args, **kwargs):
2       import urllib2
3       opener = urllib2.build_opener()
4       opener.open('http://myproject.com/api/get_project_stats')
```

The `opener.open()` call in line four runs into a timeout when running in Gunicorn, when running with `./manage.py runserver`everytihng works fine (and the api call only takes a few miliseconds.

Has anyone had the same problem? And more important: How have you solved it?

Comment: Have you tried playing with the [Gunicorn timeout settings](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/configure.html#timeout)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same issue using Gunicorn, nGinx, Django and [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

every time I did:

```
response = requests.get('http://my.url.com/here')
```

the workers would timeout

I solved the problem by switching from Syncronous (sync) workers to Asynchronous (eventlet) workers.

if you are launching command line add:

```
-k 'eventlet'
```

if you are using a config file add:

```
worker_class = "eventlet"
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer! This is it! (But I did not solve this with asynchronous eventlet workers. I solved it with doing the HTTP request in an async task using celery.)

Comment: You have to install eventlet as well. I used `pip install eventlet` and then adding `--worker-class eventlet` to the commandline.

Comment: `eventlet` is risky, everypart of your code needs to be async and libraries monkeypatched. It could have unintended consequences.